# how to remove google Chrome App Launcher from ubuntu 14.04 launcher

Tags: google-chrome

how to remove Chrome App Launcher from ubuntu 14.04 launcher , when i right click on it there is no option for it to remove or disable , just some information about the app

[image]

Comment: You can try to remove launcher entries by typing: _rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to remove launcher entries by typing:

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop
```

Comment: apostl3pol is right, this method not only deletes the launcher, but all chrome app launchers aswell. Remove only `chrome-app-list.desktop` for the effect OP requests

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works but will also remove any other chrome app shortcut that may exist on your system. To remove only the App Launcher, use:

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/applications/chrome-app-list.desktop
```